# Dynamic Programming with memoization

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

Since I am new to Dynamic programming. Can someone plz help me out to implement the memoization technique for the algorithm to the following problem.

There is a 2D matrix of N rows and M columns. Rows are number 0 to N-1 from top to bottom and columns 0 to M-1 from left to right. You are standing at (0,0).

From, A [ i ] [ j ] you can move to A [ i + 1 ] [ j ] if A [ i + 1 ] [ j ] > A [ i ] [ j ]. Or, from, A [ i ] [ j ] you can move to A [ i ] [ j + 1 ] if A [ i ] [ j + 1 ] > A [ i ] [ j ].

Moving from (0,0), what is the longest path that you can travel?

```
static int a[][],n,m;
static int find(int x,int y)
{
    if((x==n-1 && y==m-1))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(x<n-1 && y<m-1 && a[x+1][y]>a[x][y] && a[x][y+1]>a[x][y])
    {
        return Math.max(find(x+1,y),find(x,y+1))+1;
    }
    else if(x<n-1 && a[x+1][y]>a[x][y])
    {
        return find(x+1,y)+1;
    }
    else if(y<m-1 && a[x][y+1]>a[x][y])
    {
        return find(x,y+1)+1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

where..
x and y are the initial positions(i.e (0,0)),
n and m are the rows and columns resply,
a is the actual matrix.

Comment: The longest path would be m + n - 2 I believe.

Comment: @Coldspeed, the aim is to find the longest path in any direction, not to get to the top-right hand cell.

Comment: I assume you are not allowed to visit the same cell twice?

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst No no I get it. This is the Knapsack problem. I just misunderstood his question, because he said, "starting from (0, 0)"

Comment: @Coldspeedthe,@MartinBroadhurst  the above algorithm is providing correct output .I just wanted to optimize the running time using memoization technique.

Comment: @bhaskartalla can you please post the link of the challenge, so that I can see the sample input output and try my solution there.

Comment: @ GAURANG VYAS https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/2-dimensional/practice-problems/algorithm/longest-increasing-path-9/description/

Answer (score 0):

You want to use memoization to store the results of `find()` so that you can reuse them if you have calculated them already:

1. Declare another `n` by `m` array (call it `memo` say) outside the `find()` function
2. Before returning from `find()`, store the computed result in `memo[x][y]`
3. At the beginning of find(), check if `memo[x][y]` has already been filled in (is non-zero) and return it if it has

Comment: So add your code for that to your answer and tell us how it didn't work.

Comment: It is giving  the same answers with the same time and space complexity

Comment: Why do you think the time and space complexity were the same?

Comment: Actually the above problem is from a competative programming  challenge so when i submit the code then it is giving me the time limit exceeded error for both the solutions.

Comment: Try debugging and profiling it to see what it's doing.